# stub_request when request body is not predictable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stubbing

I am stubbing an http request with `stub_request`. This http request is basically a slack notification, that contains some random string (e.g. a timestamp.)

So, I can not just reuse the snippet, `rspec` spits out to me, because body differs on every execution. Is there any possibility to stub a request with, say, pattern, or I am stuck to hook e.g. the `Slack#ping`?

The dried code, jic:

**mutation**

```
class MyMutation < Mutations::Command
  def run
    slack.ping "#{rand (1..1000)}"
  end
end
```

**spec**

```
describe MyMutation do
  # ??? stub_request ???
  it 'succeeded' do
    expect(MyMutation.new.run.outcome).to be_success
  end
end
```

Thanks.

**UPD** stub request:

```
stub_request(:post, "https://hooks.slack.com/services/SECRETS").
  with(:body => {"payload"=>"{SLACK_RELATED_PROPS,\"text\":\"MY_RANDOM_HERE\"}"},
       :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', MORE_HEADERS}).
  to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```

Comment: Could you, please, add to your question how rspec/webmock suggests you to stub this request? It would be great to see the http request itself.

Comment: @AlexeyShein Added to the question, though I hardly understand how it could help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use [partial hash matching](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#matching-request-body-against-partial-hash):

```
stub_request(:post, "https://hooks.slack.com/services/SECRETS").
  with(:body => hash_including("payload"=>"{SLACK_RELATED_PROPS}"),
       :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', MORE_HEADERS}).
  to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```

I'd also recommend to provide `SLACK_RELATED_PROPS` as a hash, not as a json-encoded string. Just choose some values from there that you really care about, and strip everything else, like your random-generated value.

You can view more features in docs, such as [regex matching](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#matching-request-body-and-headers-against-regular-expressions) or even [dynamic evaluating](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#responses-with-dynamically-evaluated-parts) on `request` object.

Comment: FWIW to future readers: remember that hash_including doesn't handle partial matching of nested hashes (only exact matches), but you can solve it by doing `:body => hash_including({ a: 123, b: hash_including({ c: 'string' , d: 'string', e: 'string' }) }),` See also: https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/pull/416